# How do I push a string to stdin? Provide input via stdin on startup, then read stdin input interactively

Tags: linux, bash, stdin, interactive

Is there a way to "push" a string to the stdin stream of a program when calling it?

So that we would have the effect of

```
echo "something" | ./my_program
```

but instead of reading EOF after `"something"`, `my_program` would read its further input from the original stdin (e.g., the keyboard).

**Example:** Say we want to start a bash shell, but the first thing we would like to do inside it is to call `date`. `echo date | bash` would not do the job, as the shell would terminate after running `date`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might work:

```
(echo "something"; cat -) | ./my_program
```

It creates a sub-shell where the first line of output comes from `echo` and the rest comes from the standard input to `cat`, which is the terminal (or the script's standard input, at any rate).  I use the `-` to emphasize that `cat` is required to read from standard input — it is not simply that I've forgotten to specify `"$@"` or something after the `cat` command.  Omitting the `-` doesn't make an operational difference; it might make a comprehensibility difference.

Be aware that the input to `my_program` is no longer a terminal but a pipe connected to the terminal, which can affect the behaviour of the program.  The `cat` process introduces delays, too.

#### Expect

If that doesn't do the job, then you probably need to use [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) instead.  This is a general purpose tool for scripting interactions with other programs, and it uses pseudo-ttys (ptys) to make it appear as if a user at a terminal is communicating with the other program.
As [anishsane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/793796/anishsane) [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292170/how-do-i-push-a-string-to-stdin/29292200?noredirect=1#comment46784039_29292200), `expect` has an `interact` command that can be used to leave you with the user typing to the program after some fixed preamble.

#### Beware

Adapting this to your second scenario was not a comfortable experience:

```
(echo date; cat -) | bash -i
```

The `-i` tells Bash it is an interactive shell.  The `date` worked, and I got a prompt after it, but I didn't get any more commands executed.  Interrupt got me more prompts; pretty much everything else seemed to be ignored.  That may be `cat` doing too much buffering of its output.

I ended up killing that shell from another terminal window.  I had better luck with:

```
(echo date; cat -) | bash
```

but there were no prompts from Bash.  Be careful; make sure you know how to get out of trouble.

#### I/O Redirection Stunts

[rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) also [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292170/how-do-i-push-a-string-to-stdin/29292200?noredirect=1#comment46781540_29292200) that in this particular case, you could use:

```
{ { echo date; echo 'exec 0<&3-';} | bash -i; } 3<&0
```

That's rather clever because the trailing `3<&0` makes a copy of the original standard input (file descriptor 0) on descriptor 3, and then runs `bash -i` with its input coming from two `echo` statements.  The first requests the date.  The second re-redirects things so that the standard input now comes from file descriptor 3 (that's the `0<&3` part) — which is the original standard input, aka 'the terminal' — and closes file descriptor 3 too (that's the trailing `-`; it is a [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) extension over POSIX shell [I/O redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07)).

Comment: That's where I was heading, but you're quicker :-) ... Easiest way to test your example is (echo "foo"; cat -) | cat

Comment: Why `cat -`? Doesn't `cat` on its own simply take its input from stdin?

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yes; `cat` reads its standard input, but I put the `-` there to emphasize that `cat` is reading from standard input and that I haven't simply forgotten to specify a file name.

Comment: For this particular case, you could use `{ { echo date; echo 'exec 0<&3-';} | bash -i; } 3<&0`

Comment: @rici: clever; yes, that does work quite nicely.  You could cheat and simply use `echo 'exec </dev/tty'` too, and it works fine as long as standard input actually is coming from the terminal (but wreaks havoc if it isn't, unlike the more complex but thorough solution you suggest).

Comment: @rici: Your comment deserves to be represented as an answer in its own right, _with an an explanation_.

Comment: On another note, you can also think of using [`expect`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) to supply the required commands at first prompt & `interact` after they are complete...

Comment: @anishsane: As in _If that doesn't do the job, then you probably need to use [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) instead_?  :D  Granted, that's fairly well hidden now that I added material at the end, but it was there.

Comment: ^^ Probably yours a better way of wording it... :-)

Comment: @mklement0: Fortunately, Jonathan Leffler provided the explanation. A catalog of all the specific ways of invoking a REPL after reading one or more program files for various shells/interpreters/etc. would have been more work than I had time for last night. :)

Answer (score 1):

To complement [Jonathan Leffler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29292200/45375) with a **potentially simpler, but limited alternative**:

**IF**

- `./my_program` is `bash`, as in the OP's example
- AND  it's acceptable that side effects produced by the startup command are:

  - EITHER: NOT visible AT ALL to the `bash` instance that *stays open*
  - OR: limited to inheriting all *modified* variables as *exported* variables

you can try the following:

```
bash -c "$(<command that produces Bash commands>); exec bash -i"
```

Using the example of the `date` command as the startup command:

```
bash -c "$(echo 'date'); exec bash -i"
```

This **executes `date` and then *replaces* the running `bash` instance with a *new* instance, which then *stays open*** (due to neither receiving stdin input nor having a command passed to it via `-c`).

To illustrate that any changes made to the *startup* shell's environment are NOT propagated to the one that ultimately *stays open*, consider this:

```
bash -c "$(echo 'date; foo=bar; echo $foo'); exec bash -i"
```

This prints the date and assigns and prints variable `$foo`, but if you then execute `echo $foo` *again*, it will NOT be defined, because **the shell instance that ultimately stays open does NOT inherit its state from the one that executed the startup commands**.

You can ***partially* work around this limitation** by **passing `-a` to `bash`**, which then causes **all variables modified or created by the startup commands** to be **automatically exported**:

```
bash -ac "$(echo 'date; foo=bar; echo $foo'); exec bash -i"
```

Now, if you execute `echo $foo` again in the stay-open instance, it WILL print `bar`.

Note:

- Such variables effectively become *environment* variables, which means that any child processes created by the stay-open shell also see them.