# How can I open shell and then execute a command inside it

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, conemu, cmder

What I want is to open default shell, then call another and execute a command there.

Was trying something like this:

`c:/Windows/System32/bash.exe -c "zsh & zstyle"`

or

`cmd /k "c:/Windows/System32/bash.exe -c zsh" & zstyle` - this open shell but doesn't run a commands

or

`c:/Windows/System32/bash.exe -c "zsh -c 'zstyle'"`

Currently I am using a cmder/conemu terminal for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, passing a startup to command to `zsh` with `-c` *and* keeping it open for interactive use (with `-i`) doesn't work.

<sup>Disclaimer: The following solutions were tested from a regular Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`), not cmder/conemu, though I'd expect them to work there too.

To try them from PowerShell (v3+), insert `--%` as the first argument after (right after `bash.exe`).</sup>

Here's a workaround:

```
c:/Windows/System32/bash.exe -c "zsh -c 'zstyle' && exec zsh -i"
```

Note that command `zstyle` is executed in a *different, transient* `zsh` instance, so this approach won't work for commands whose purpose is to *modify* the environment of the interactive shell that stays open.
If that is a requirement, things get more complicated (this solution courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29292200/45375)):

```
c:/Windows/System32/bash.exe -c "{ { echo 'zstyle'; echo 'exec 0<&3-';} | zsh -i; } 3<&0"
```

Note, however, that both commands being executed will be *printed* before their output, if any, is shown, preceded by the prompt - as if the commands had been typed interactively.